# Magento: Add two products for a category on same product page

Tags: custom-options, addtocart, product-page

I would like to show 2 products on a product page in magento for a category, both having complete details and separate "Add to Cart" buttons. Can anyone give me some directions how can I get this done? I am a newbie and i have a project with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the Second product as related product from backend or any other relationship  , Replicate the Code for that Product as well

Comment: Both the products have the same Part Number with different prefix. Will this work? And also it would be of great help if you could provide some code to implement.